# How to permute correlations between several pairs of variables in R?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, permutation, correlation, parallel.foreach

I would like to compute the correlation between pairs of variables from two data frames, ideally using cor.test, so I can compare the p value from using either the estimate or the statistic. My real data (rather than practice dummy data) has 20 samples and 40 variables in df1 and 20 samples and 345 variables in df2.

Some examples where they have looked at permutating correlations between two variables use a for loop, https://bookdown.org/curleyjp0/psy317l_guides5/permutation-testing.html#correlation-coefficient-permutation-tests and https://dgarcia-eu.github.io/SocialDataScience/5_SocialNetworkPhenomena/056_PermutationTests/PermutationTests, which works if only having two variables/vectors.

I'm attempting to use foreach to permute each of my y variables in df2 1,000 times, and then calculate the p value by looking at the number of times the permuted statistic >= original statistic / number of permutations. I've been practicing with 10 permutations and a smaller dataset to see if I can get my code working

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(round(runif(n=12*12, min=1, max=20), 0), ncol=12))
colnames(df) <- paste0("a", ncol(df))
df2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(round(runif(n=12*20, min=1, max=20), 0), ncol=20))
colnames(df2) <- paste("b", ncol(df2) )
comp <- expand.grid(colnames(df1), colnames(df2))


res <-  foreach(i=1:nrow(comp), .combine=rbind, .packages=c("magrittr", "dplyr")) %dopar% {
perm <- \(){
N <- 10
samp <- sample(nrow(df2))
cor.test(df[, comp[i,1]], df2[samp, comp[i,2]], method="spearman", exact=FALSE)[c("estimate")]
}
perm_stat <- replicate(N, perm())
orig_stat <- cor.test(df[, comp[i,1]], df2[, comp[i,2]], method="spearman", exact=FALSE)[c("estimate")] 
(sum(abs(perm_stat) >= abs(orig_stat)) + 1)/N 
   }

  res2 <- as.data.frame(unlist(res)) %>% dplyr::mutate(Var1=comp[,1], Var2=comp[,2])
```

If I hash out everything bar orig_stat, it runs to get the coefficient/estimate of the correlations between the variables in df and df2. But is not obviously carrying out the permutation. Shall I attempt to use a double loop via foreach or look at an alternative approach such as parallelised version of Map e.g mcmapply.

```
   ##double loop format 
   out <- foreach(j=1:ncol(df1), .combine = 'rbind', .packages=c("magrittr", "dplyr")) %:%
      foreach(i = 1:ncol(df2), .combine = 'c') %dopar% {
       a <- cor.test(df1[,j], df2[,i], method = "spearman")$p.value
     }
```

Comment: your title is an issue relating to speed, but your body text is not about that, but something about how obvious it is that permutations are happening ?

Comment: @NirGraham, I've changed the title now - its more relating to how to devise correct code to permute correlations when the variables I am in interested in correlating are in two data frames.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some confusion here about the use of a permutation test. `cor.test` is already giving the information you need--no permutations required.

Say, for example, `cor.test(x, y, method = "spearman")` returns a p-value of 0.05. For a two-sided test using Spearman's *rho* statistic, the interpretation is that Spearman's rank correlation coefficient between `x` and `y[sample(length(y))]` will be further from 0 than the coefficient between `x` and `y` approximately 5% of the time.

Similarly, if we repeatedly called `cor.test(x, y[sample(length(y))], method = "spearman")`, we would see a p-value less than 0.05 approximately 5% of the time. Demonstrating:

```
set.seed(293885308L)
x <- runif(20)
y <- runif(20)
correl <- cor(x, y, method = "spearman")

# a single `cor.test`
(p <- cor.test(x, y, method = "spearman")$p.value)
#> [1] 0.04984582

# a permutation test on top of `cor.test`
mean(replicate(1e5, cor.test(x, y[sample(20)], method = "spearman")$p.value) <= p)
#> [1] 0.04982

# a permutation test instead of `cor.test`
mean(abs(replicate(1e6, cor(x, y[sample(20)], method = "spearman"))) >= correl)
#> [1] 0.04973
```

For the relatively small datasets described in the question, we can quickly and easily get the p-value of all pairwise column combinations:

```
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(20*40), 20, 40))
df2 <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(20*345), 20, 345))

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  cor.test = mapply(\(y) sapply(df, \(x) cor.test(x, y, method = "spearman")$p.value), df2),
  times = 10
)
#> Unit: seconds
#>      expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#>  cor.test 1.739906 1.753571 1.818344 1.773926 1.841813 1.989383    10
```

Comment: thank you for this. Its more that I would like to use permutations to shuffle both my x and y (or y only) or more specifically ranks, as I am using Spearman, to  then compare the number of times the test statistic from the permutations is greater than or equal to the test statistic from the original correlation calculation, divided by the number of permutations. Not entirely sure if I can say that the null hypothesis is that the correlation is rank dependent, alternative being that they are not rank dependent , which can then be looked at using the p value from the permuation?

Comment: I understand from your code what you are trying to do. What I'm saying is that adding a permutation test on top of a well behaved statistical test (`cor.test` here) is redundant, as I demonstrated. Don't worry about the permutation test, just use `cor.test`! As a side note shuffling just `x` or just `y` or both `x` and `y` are all equivalent when sampling correlations of permutations.

Comment: Would it depend on the original dataset though? So if each of the pairs of observations from variables x and y contributed to the correlation/relationship seen, then permutations wouldn't make a difference. However, what if my original correlation coefficient without permutations was largely influenced by only one or two pairs out of all of x and y, resampling randomly would help identify whether there is a true correlation or whether we're unlikely to see that (if we don't have the very few data points that drive it ). Maybe I need a different approach altogether...

Comment: That's exactly what `cor.test` does. It approximates the probability that the absolute value of the (in this case Spearman) correlation coefficient of randomly paired observations is greater than or equal to the coefficient from the observed pairings.

Comment: The approach depends on your ultimate goal, which wasn't included in your question. Whatever approach you choose, it would be good to keep in mind that you are likely to get some very low p-values among 40*345 = 13800 statistical tests, even if `df` and `df2` were randomly and independently generated as in your example.

Comment: if possible, please could you provide a source/link for the cor.test in relation to your comment above , yes I plan to do some form of multiple comparison correction (e.g FDR or something along those lines).

Comment: The paper referenced in`?cor.test`: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2347111?origin=crossref